# Instagram API: getting and setting "Photos are private" field

Tags: api, instagram

Is there a way that I can get and set from API "Photos are private" checkbox from "Edit profile" section? I can't find it, but maybe I am missing something. :)

Thanks!

Best,
D

Answer (score 0):

API not available for doing this currently, you have use Instagram App to set profile to public/private